# Cannot load shapefile with readOGR - ogrinfo: all features NULL

Tags: r, rgdal, r-sf

I'm trying to plot some maps in Ubuntu 18.04 . I've downloaded some shapefiles but cannot read them with "readOGR" function.

I've installed "libdgal" and "libproj-dev".

```
sudo apt-get install libudunits2-dev libgdal-dev libgeos-dev libproj-dev
```

But when using:

```
library(rgdal)     # R wrapper around GDAL/OGR
library(ggplot2)   # for general plotting
library(ggmap)    # for fortifying shapefiles

# First read in the shapefile, using the path to the shapefile and the shapefile name minus the
# extension as arguments
shapefile <- readOGR("/home/ogonzales/Escritorio/maps_in_r/", "BAS_LIM_DEPARTAMENTO")
```

I get this error:

```
Error in readOGR("/home/ogonzales/Escritorio/maps_in_r/", "BAS_LIM_DEPARTAMENTO") : 
  no features found
Además: Warning message:
In ogrInfo(dsn = dsn, layer = layer, encoding = encoding, use_iconv = use_iconv,  :
  ogrInfo: all features NULL
```

This is the message I get after loading "rgdal" package:

```
library(rgdal)     # R wrapper around GDAL/OGR
Loading required package: sp
rgdal: version: 1.3-2, (SVN revision 755)
 Geospatial Data Abstraction Library extensions to R successfully loaded
 Loaded GDAL runtime: GDAL 2.2.3, released 2017/11/20
 Path to GDAL shared files: /usr/share/gdal/2.2
 GDAL binary built with GEOS: TRUE 
 Loaded PROJ.4 runtime: Rel. 4.9.3, 15 August 2016, [PJ_VERSION: 493]
 Path to PROJ.4 shared files: (autodetected)
 Linking to sp version: 1.2-7
```

Path of file:

The file's path is correct:

```
list.files('/home/ogonzales/Escritorio/maps_in_r/', pattern='\\.shp$') #"BAS_LIM_DEPARTAMENTO.shp"
file.exists('/home/ogonzales/Escritorio/maps_in_r/BAS_LIM_DEPARTAMENTO.shp') #TRUE
```

**UPDATE 1:**

Doing:

```
library(sf)

shapefile <- sf::st_read("/home/ogonzales/Escritorio/maps_in_r/BAS_LIM_DEPARTAMENTO.shp")
```

Returns:

```
Cannot open data source /home/ogonzales/Escritorio/maps_in_r/BAS_LIM_DEPARTAMENTO.shp
Error in CPL_read_ogr(dsn, layer, as.character(options), quiet, type,  : 
  Open failed.
```

**UPDATE 2**:

```
rgdal::ogrListLayers("/home/ogonzales/Escritorio/maps_in_r/BAS_LIM_DEPARTAMENTO")
```

Returns:

```
Error in rgdal::ogrListLayers("/home/ogonzales/Escritorio/maps_in_r/BAS_LIM_DEPARTAMENTO") : 
  Cannot open data source
```

And:

```
sf::st_layers("/home/ogonzales/Escritorio/maps_in_r/BAS_LIM_DEPARTAMENTO")
Cannot open data source /home/ogonzales/Escritorio/maps_in_r/BAS_LIM_DEPARTAMENTO
Error in CPL_get_layers(dsn, options, do_count) : Open failed.
```

**UPDATE 2:**

```
list.files("/home/ogonzales/Escritorio/maps_in_r/")
[1] "BAS_LIM_DEPARTAMENTO.dbf" "BAS_LIM_DEPARTAMENTO.prj" "BAS_LIM_DEPARTAMENTO.sbn"
[4] "BAS_LIM_DEPARTAMENTO.sbx" "BAS_LIM_DEPARTAMENTO.shp" "BAS_LIM_DEPARTAMENTO.shx"
[7] "maps_in_r.Rproj"
```

Comment: What does `rgdal::ogrListLayers` tell you?

Comment: `library(sf)` : `sf::st_read(".../...shp")` is the 'new' way to read shape files in R.

Comment: @alistaire I got this: Error in rgdal::ogrListLayers() : missing dsn

Comment: @SymbolixAU see the update 1.

Comment: You have to call it on the shapefile; it should tell you what layers it has. The sf equivalent is `sf::st_layers`.

Comment: @alistaire pls, see my update 2. It maybe a corrupted file. May you point me to somewhere where I can get a correct shp file?

Comment: What is it a shapefile of? If you're just looking for one to experiment with, you can get the path of a built-in one with `system.file('shape/nc.shp', package = 'sf')`.

Comment: @alistaire it's a map of Perú, my country.

Comment: There seem to be a lot of useful things at [GeoIDEP](http://www.geoidep.gob.pe/), or you could extract what you want from [Natural Earth](https://github.com/ropenscilabs/rnaturalearth).

Comment: can you provide the results of list.files("/home/ogonzales/Escritorio/maps_in_r/")

Comment: @sebdalgarno see my update 2. ty

Comment: @alistaire I can plot the built-in map found in 'shape/nc.shp'. So I think it's something with the files I've donwloaded. I'll try the GeolDEP or Natural Earth websites and let you know. ty